# Where are these configuration files on Windows 2016 server installation?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I am not a system engeneer (I am a software developer) and moreover I don't have strong background on Windows (I know better Linux) and I have the following problem.

In order to configure a SIEM agent I have to provide the following information related to the location of some configuration files that should be on a **Windows Server 2016** machine but I can't find these files on my machine.

- **autoexec.bat**: from what I know this files was used to perform some batch operation at Windows startup. It was located into C:\ folder. I can't find it. I am not understanding if this file doesn't exist anymore (maybe replaced by the use of registry).
- **boot.ini**: from what I know it also was into the C:\ folder and nowdays doesn't exist anymore (maybe replaced by replaced with Boot Configuration Data (BCD)).
- **config.sys**: also this file I think exist no more on a Windows 2016 Server.
- **io.sys**: also this file I think exist no more on a Windows 2016 Server.
- **msdos.sys**: also this file I think exist no more on a Windows 2016 Server.
- **ntbootdd.sys**: also this file I think exist no more on a Windows 2016 Server.
- **ntdetect.sys**: also this file I think exist no more on a Windows 2016 Server.
- **ntldr**: it should be present but I can't find it on the virtual machine running my Windows 2016 Server.

Are my reasoning correct? Is it ok that these files doesn't exist anymore on a Windows 2016 Server installation? And what about the **ntldr**? Why I can't find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these files were removed several decades ago – or rather they were never part of Windows NT series to begin with. The rest were removed around ~2006 (with Windows Vista/Srv2008).

You should generally avoid using security software that was written for Server 2003.

- The files `ntldr`, `boot.ini`, and `ntdetect.com` (not .sys) were part of the NTLDR bootloader that was used by Windows XP/Srv2003. They no longer exist because NTLDR has been [replaced by BOOTMGR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_6_startup_process) starting with Windows Vista/Srv2008.

  Instead of boot.ini, BOOTMGR uses a Registry-based "BCD" configuration file (and to some extent, the EFI NVRAM as well).

  Some functions of ntdetect.com were removed entirely, others moved to "winload.efi" (or winload.exe on BIOS systems).
- Note that on modern UEFI systems, the bootloader (together with its configuration) is always kept in the "EFI System Partition" separately from the OS – it is never on the C:\ volume.

  By default, Windows installations post-XP/Srv2003 imitate this also on BIOS systems, creating a separate "Microsoft System Partition" which holds the bootloader and its configuration. So you still won't find a C:\BOOTMGR file anymore.
- The files `io.sys`, `msdos.sys`, `config.sys`, and `autoexec.bat` were part of MS-DOS.  (Specifically, io.sys + msdos.sys held the actual MS-DOS kernel.)

  They don't exist on Windows NT series operating systems as those OS **do not use MS-DOS**. (Windows XP/Srv2003 were NT-based but still included *empty* 'io.sys' and 'msdos.sys' files to appease some old 16-bit programs, but those files already weren't used as part of the boot process.)

  I would even say that expecting to find those files on Server 2016 is almost as nonsensical as expecting to find those files on Linux.

  Some of the tasks previously performed by autoexec.bat now correspond to different Windows Registry areas – e.g. global [environment variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables) are set by the Session Manager, TSRs have been replaced by services under the Service Control Manager, and so on.